# Absolute value and norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Can I write, absolute value in terms of the norm?

Like  $|a|$ as $\|a\|^2$, where a is a scalar.

Definition of norm square is :

$\|v\|^2 = \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}.$

Where $a_1,\ldots,a_{n}$ are all scalars.

Comment: Yes because $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$, so it is the case above when $n=1$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. More specifically:
Any $p$-Norm on $\mathbb R^1$ is actually the absolute value. Even more, any norm on $\mathbb R^1$ is infact a multiple of the absolute value, with
$$ ||x|| = |x|\cdot ||1|| $$